# Seeking Great Britain landuse data for free (for academic reasons)?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, united-kingdom, land-use

For the academic project I am working on, I would need to have the Great Britain landuse data.So far I looked for them in several websites but I did not find anything that was for free and with a good quality (I found some data in osm-x-tractor.org but they are very incomplete).

Is there a good website where I can find these information for free?

Eventually, is there any easy method to extract this large amount of information from OpenStreetMap or any other similar website by myself?

Comment: Have you seen anything from the links posted in this question? [Where to get Land Use data for the UK?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41600/where-to-get-land-use-data-for-the-uk)

Comment: Yeah from that other post the CORINE data is free. OS MasterMap is free through EDINA but it is too detailed to be used at a GB level.

Comment: So you want data about landuse like woods, meadows, beaches, industrial, residential, agricultural etc? For whole GB?

Comment: OS Mastermap does not yet have anything close to what would be considered to be detailed land use, although the OS have talked about introducing it.

Comment: Landscape >Land Use Class http://magic.defra.gov.uk/magicmap.aspx

Comment: related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41600/where-to-get-land-use-data-for-the-uk

Comment: Thank you everybody for your suggestions. I had already looked at the the previous answer, but I must confess I did not noticed the CORINE data. Also I took a look at the Magic website but I did not find what I was looking for because I was interested in a classification where each polygon is classified as "industrial","agricultural" and so on (that is not available for all GB or is not that precise in Magic). I also found this http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html but it does not provide the data as shapefiles, so I do not know if I can actually take advantage of it.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  Also, if you are seeking open data then the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Since I found the data I was looking for, here I report the links I found more useful. The following links contains connections to free landuse shapefile data for UK landuse:

[Landuse data from the CORINE project, updated 2012; the data available from this website cover ALL the GB area, but they have a lower definition in comparison to the third link I list](https://catalogue.ceh.ac.uk/documents/32533dd6-7c1b-43e1-b892-e80d61a5ea1d)

[Landuse data from the CORINE project, updated 2007](http://www.ceh.ac.uk/services/land-cover-map-2007)

[Landuse data for England, Scotland and Wales (separated). These data are very specific, but they do not cover all the GB area, i.e. there will be some spaces where no data are provided](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html)